# How to extract ROI on grayscale image using edge detection

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, anomaly-detection

I want to extract the white area on the image below (ROI) by using edge detection. I want to do this beacouse I must get very precise mask of white region. The image loks like this:

[image]

If I use some of matlab's inbuild functions the problem is that I also get edges outside of the white areas (on the border between black area and gray area), so if I erode outside edge I lose corners of white region at the both sides...

[image]

I also have to close the whole white area to get mask, after properly detected edges...

Any other suggestions to calculate mask of white area on the first image? I already tried thresholding and the method was quite succesfull...

Answer (score 0):

If the images all look like that it looks really easy to solve:

```
Ibw=I>somevaluebiggerthangrey;
```

Then, if you want the perimeter, do

```
Iperim=bwperim(Ibw);
```

You shouled be able to find the value of `somevaluebiggerthangrey` as you rimage has clearly 3 colors. Find the "peak" value of those colors (e.g. result could be `0, 0.5 and 1`) and give a value between the two peaks, such as `somevaluebiggerthangrey=0.75`. You shoudl be able to do this automatically using `histogram` and maybe `findpeaks`